# Using Django Label Values

Tags: django, templates, view

I have a label with the name Lab in my template. How do I use the label value in my view?

**Template**

```html
{%for product in products %}
<div class="column">
    <img src=" {{product.image.url}}"  class="w3-bar-item w3-circle" style={"width:50px";"high:10px;"}>
    <label name="Lab" id="my">{{product.id}}</label>
    <p>{{product.name}} {{product.Price}} SR</p>
    <form  action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" id="dd">Add to my order</button>
     </form>
</div>
```

**View**

```
 if data.is_valid():
 table = models.Get()

 table.count = data.cleaned_data['count']
 table.order_id_id = order_id
 table.product_id_id = request.POST.get['Lab']
 table.save()
```

Comment: Do you have a label or an input with name `Lab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an hidden input inside the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Lab" value="{{product.id}}"/>
```

Don't forgot to remove the name attribute from the label you define.

Inputs fields are the only value which are sent within the request.

Regards